# Find the probability of the following event.

Tags: probability

Bayesylvania is awash with citizens not all of whom can be trusted to tell the truth. A
traveler finds himself at a T-junction in an area populated by the Asciis and Bisciis in
the ratio 11 to 5. A Biscii always lie but an Ascii tells the truth three quarters of the
time, giving independent answers to all questions, even to immediately repeated ones.

Question:
The traveler asks one particular citizen three times whether he should go to the
left or to the right to reach the local village. Each time he receives the same
answer “left”. What should the traveler do now? Have his chances of finding the
village been altered by asking the question three times?

Comment: I think that the probability will not change since the answers to all the questions are independent... I also know that the probability for an answer to be correct is 0.516... But I am not sure

Comment: If the traveller asked a million times then he is very probably talking to a consistent liar.  This suggests that the more times he gets a consistent answer affects his chance of finding the village.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets say A means he got three times the same answer and B means he got the truth.

we are looking for $$P(B|A) = \frac{P(A - and - B)}{P(A)}$$

three times the same answer can be achived if we tallked to a Biscii  for a chance of $$\frac{5}{16}$$ or if we tallked a Asciis and he either lied 3 times or told the truth 3 times for a chance of $$\frac{11}{16}*\frac{3^3}{4^3}+\frac{11}{16}*\frac{1^3}{4^3}=\frac{11}{16}*\frac{3^3+1^3}{4^3}$$
so $$ P(A) = \frac{5}{16} +\frac{11}{16}*\frac{3^3+1^3}{4^3}$$
now P(A and B) is the chance we were told the truth 3 times witch is only poliblle if we tallked to a Asciis and the chance is $$\frac{11}{16}*\frac{3^3}{4^3}$$
puting all this into a calculator gives us $$P(B|A) = \frac{297}{628}$$
that is a litlle less then 0.5, meaning its more likely to be false.

if we redo the calculations only he asked on time we get the chance of getting the truth is $$\frac{11}{16}*\frac{3}{4} = \frac{33}{64}$$
that is above 0.5 but the chance the difrence is less then before so you'r chance of going the way you should is lower.